# Camel restConfiguration set host to value of a route

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, openshift, openshift-origin, fabric8

I have an openshift service that is running a spring boot container and in it I have defined a restConfiguration:

```
        <restConfiguration apiContextPath="api-docs" bindingMode="json" component="servlet" contextPath="/demos">
            <apiProperty key="cors" value="true" />
            <apiProperty key="api.title" value="openshift demo" />
            <apiProperty key="api.version" value="1.0.0" />     
        </restConfiguration>
```

This all works nicely and I and call the api-docs endpoint, which generates the following swagger:

```
{
   "swagger":"2.0",
   "info":{
      "version":"1.0.0",
      "title":"openshift demo"
   },
   "host":"0.0.0.0",
   "basePath":"/demos",
   "tags":[
      {
         "name":"bitcoinaccount"
      }
   ]
```

I would like to set the value of host to the value of the url the swagger is being called on. The service is reachable through a route that fabric8 is creating:

```
spec:
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: openshiftdemo-service
```

If this isnt possible, I would like to unset the field entirely.

I have tried using environment variable (but none seem to be translated, even those that are working in the rest of the application context), all values for hostnameResolver, setting host to "", "none", "null" and removing it.

Ive tried looking in the camel jira for a fix in a later version but I cant seem to find it. Ive googled the problem and tried the solutions listed there.

im using: spring-boot 1.4.1, camel 2.18.1, openshift origin 3.11